# Match values from 2 arrays with equal index

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I match values from these arrays with the same index?

```
int[] array = { 4, 4, 4, 0 };
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 4, 0 };
```

I want to match "4" from "array" - index 2 with "4" from "array1" with the same index

I tried matching the same values with

```
int i, j = 4;
bool match = (array.Contains(i) && array1.Contains(j));
```

and then comparing indexes

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, i);
int index1 = Array.IndexOf(array1, j);
```

but this fails because index == 0 and index1 == 2

Comment: you want to check?

Comment: Can you please clarify what result you expect from your sample arrays? Or even from simpler [1], [2] pair of arrays?

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is your friend here.  You can use an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) of the `Select()` call to create an anonymous object containing each array value as well as its corresponding index.  Once you have this collection of key/value pairs, the solution is rather simple.

```
var matches = array1.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value})
                    .Where(x => x.Value == array2[x.Index])
                    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: return the key/value pair. not just the value. because given the OP example you'll get `{ 4, 0 }` but you won't know which 4 matched. So just do a to list after the where.

Comment: Correct, if you need to know the specific instance of a number that matched you'll want to forego the final `Select` clause so you have access to the index.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.Zip(array1)`. This gives a set of tuples.